# Turn off javascript on iframes only

Tags: javascript

Is there a way so that pages in `<iframe>` tags can't use javascript?

Turn off javascript on iframes only but not on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [sandbox attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) on the iframe.

```
<iframe sandbox></iframe>
```

> The sandbox attribute, when specified, enables a set of extra
>   restrictions on any content hosted by the iframe. Its value must be an
>   unordered set of unique space-separated tokens that are ASCII
>   case-insensitive. The allowed values are allow-same-origin,
>   allow-top-navigation, allow-forms, and allow-scripts. When the
>   attribute is set, the content is treated as being from a unique
>   origin, forms and scripts are disabled, links are prevented from
>   targeting other browsing contexts, and plugins are disabled. The
>   allow-same-origin keyword allows the content to be treated as being
>   from the same origin instead of forcing it into a unique origin, the
>   allow-top-navigation keyword allows the content to navigate its
>   top-level browsing context, and the allow-forms and allow-scripts
>   keywords re-enable forms and scripts respectively (though scripts are
>   still prevented from creating popups).

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't change anything in an iframe, unless it is in the same domain as the page containing it for security purposes.

The only way around this would be have your server act as a proxy and filter JS server-side.

Comment: so does this mean that if I want to disable javascript on an iframe, the browser should go also being javascript disabled?

Comment: @Reigel Yes. AFAIK no major browser has a feature like that (disabling JS in iframes only)

Comment: @Reigel: pretty much, unless the content of the iframe is from the same web site (domain name). However, if you describe more about your problem, we might come up with another way to accomplish your goal.